# How to trigger a mouseover event for an SVG element below other elements

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

Currently learning d3.js v5
I am working with a graph that displays a tooltip when an area of the graph is hovered over, along with highlighting the graph area selected.  The issue I have noticed is that whenever any bar or line is hovered over, the tooltip won't display, and the area is no longer highlighted until I move off that area.
I was wondering if there is a way to have the mouseover element read the SVG element under the bars and lines or if I also need to add event listeners to the bars and lines.

I could potentially add another rect element that is invisible over all the other elements so that it is triggered first, however I also want to add interactivity to the bars and lines in the graph.

```
d3.csv("test.csv").then(function(dataset) {
  backBar.selectAll("rectBack")
          .data(dataset)
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("class","rectBack")
          .attr("x",(d)=>xScale((d.year)))
          .attr("y",margin.top)
          .attr("width",(w)/dataset.length)
          .attr("height",h-topBottom)
          .attr("opacity",0)
          .attr("fill","lightgrey")
          .on("mouseover",function(d){
            d3.select(this)
              .attr("opacity",0.3);
            showTooltip(d);
          })
          .on("mouseout",function(){
            d3.select(this)
              .attr("opacity",0);
            removeTooltip();
          })
  function showTooltip(d){
        d3.select("body")
            .append("div")
            .attr("class","tooltip")
            .attr("opacity",0.5)
            .html("<h5>"+d.year+"</h5>")
            .style("top", yLineScale(d.line1) + svgPos.offsetTop)
            .style("left", xScale(d.year) + svgPos.offsetLeft)
        console.log(d);
  }
  function removeTooltip(){
        d3.selectAll(".tooltip")
          .remove("*");
  }
}
```

`svgPos` is a variable that holds the coordinates of the SVG
`yLineScale` and `xScale` are both scales for the X and Y axis respectively
Link to image of graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKmCy.jpg

Comment: Have you tried to use the .raise() function on the desired svg element so there isn't anything ontop of it?

Comment: That would make sense but I don't want the desired SVG element over the bars and lines in my graph for cosmetic reasons, but I also want users to be able to trigger other events with the bars and lines of the graph. If the bottom was raised over the other elements, users would no longer be able to interact with them.